# How to check if cookies are empty or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to check if cookie is present with value or not. But I wonder if there is some quick and good way of doing so since if I need to check 3 cookies it seems bad to check with `if` or `try`.

Why it does not assign empty string to my variable if cookie is not present? Instead it shows `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

My code (it works, but it seems too big for this task, I think there should be a better way of doing this)

```
// First I need to asign empty variables and I don't like this
string randomHash = string.Empty;
string browserHash = string.Empty;
int userID = 0;

// Second I need to add this huge block of try/catch just to get cookies
// It's fine since I need all three values in this example so if one fails all fails
try
{
    randomHash = Convert.ToString(Request.Cookies["randomHash"].Value);
    browserHash = Convert.ToString(Request.Cookies["browserHash"].Value);
    userID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["userID"].Value);
}
catch
{
    // And of course there is nothing to catch here
}
```

As you can see I have this huge block just to get cookies. What I would like is something like this:

```
// Gives value on success, null on cookie that is not found
string randomHash = Convert.ToString(Request.Cookies["randomHash"].Value);
string browserHash = Convert.ToString(Request.Cookies["browserHash"].Value);
int userID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["userID"].Value);
```

Edit
Maybe I can somehow override the `.Value` method to my liking?

Comment: Perhaps this isnot ideal, but there's really nothing 'huge' about that block of code.

Comment: Still I would love to use the second one. If this is the only way than fine, but it just seems to me that there should be a better one.

Comment: Okay, you could use something like `Convert.ToString(Request.Cookies["randomHash"] != null ? Request.Cookies["randomHash"].Value : "");` per line, but that just gives longer lines.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment Excatly what I was looking for. Submit answer and I will accept it.

Comment: What is wrong with you guys! (or is it just me?) but why are you guys explicitly converting a `string` to a `string` for? @Mr.Disappointment: You have 13K rep!!!

Comment: @musefan Hey, I was just passing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just check if the cookie is null:

```
if(Request.Cookies["randomHash"] != null)
{
   //do something
}
```

NOTE: The "Better" way of doing this is to write good code that is both readable and reliable. It doesn't assign empty string because this is not how C# works, you are trying to call the `Value` property on a `null` object (`HttpCookie`) - you cannot use null objects because there is nothing to use.

Converting to an `int` you still need to avoid parse errors, but you can use this built in method:

```
int.TryParse(cookieString, out userID);
```

which brings on another point? Why are you storing the userID in a cookie? this can be changed by the end user - I don't know how you plan on using this but would I be right to assume this is a big security hole?

---

or with a little helper function:

```
public string GetCookieValueOrDefault(string cookieName)
{
   HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[cookieName];
   if(cookie == null)
   {
      return "";
   }  
   return cookie.Value;
}
```

then...

```
string randomHash = GetCookieValueOrDefault("randomHash");
```

---

Or with an Extension method:

```
public static string GetValueOrDefault(this HttpCookie cookie)
{
   if(cookie == null)
   {
      return "";
   }  
   return cookie.Value;  
}
```

then...

```
string randomHash = Request.Cookies["randomHash"].GetValueOrDefault();
```

Comment: One correction to your otherwise great answer - int.TryParse does not use try/catch. It avoids the try/catch for efficiency reasons. This is why it's **always** better to use the TryParse methods rather than wrapping in a try/catch block.